# Booklet PDF to Readable PDF

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I have a booklet PDF which has two sides in each page. example

```
Page 48 and Page 1
Page 47 and Page 2
```

I want to change the PDF as single PDF as 1, 2, 3, ...48 for reading.

How to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You may wish to edit your question to clarify what you are attempting to accomplish. For instance, are you wishing to do this kind of operation soley in Adobe Acrobat (as tagged) or some other pdf software (i.e. any other third-party app)? Can your preferred solution include the command-line (perhaps a script)? Are you attempting to do this in bulk?

Answer (score 1):

Making a PDF of a book actually look like a book isn’t as straightforward as you might hope. It is tempting to turn on the Spreads checkbox (in the Export PDF dialog box) in order to show what the book will look like, but I encourage you not to. First of all, as you found out, InDesign cannot merge the two pages (last page of one chapter and the first page of the next) together into a single spread. But second, all you’re really doing is telling InDesign to pretend that the whole spread is a single page — and that the document is made up of single-sided pages. Of course, you’d also need to draw your own line in the document to show where the spine is… Blech.

Instead, give this job to Acrobat. After opening the PDF in Acrobat, you can adjust the view (View > Page Display) to show the spreads. Make sure the Show Cover Page During Two-Up is selected, too, or else page 1 will become the left-hand part of a two-page spread.

[image]

But you don’t want to have to tell your client to do this. So open File > Properties (Command/Ctrl-D) and, in the Initial View tab, set the Page Layout to “Two-Up (Cover Page).”

[image]

Then click OK and save the document. That way, when you client opens it, it will open just the way you intended. (Unless they open it in some other PDF viewer, like OS X Preview, which doesn’t read the Initial View tag properly. In that case, you’re back to telling them to choose View > Page Display > Two-Up.

Reference :- [Make It Look Like a Book in the Acrobat PDF](http://indesignsecrets.com/make-it-look-like-a-book-in-the-acrobat-pdf.php)

Comment: I want to save as well as it works in both when a user reads or prints it. Will it work when anyone opens or print the pages. I need the pages to be read sequentially or printed sequentially

Comment: According to your requirement I provide the answer.

Comment: Sure and will follow this and will update you. thank you

Comment: i was trying to convert a booklet PDF to Normal and not Normal to Booklet PDF. i followed the above steps and don't get the expected output